# Python pygame noob question about animation

Tags: python, pygame

could you help me with a problem I have? I am a new person with regard to programming and to guide me I am using the book: How to think like a computer scientist 3rd edition. And it could not solve exercise 2 of chapter 17. This says that an error occurs when clicking on any frame that is on the right side of the sprite, which causes the animation to start, in theory it should only do the animation if it is you click directly on the sprite, I tried to solve it in many ways but I couldn't, could you help me ?, I think the error occurs in this part

```
 return ( x >= my_x and x + my_width and y >= my_y and y < my_y + my_height)
```

but I'm not sure, for anything I leave you all the code I have

```
import pygame
gravity = 0.025
my_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
class QueenSprite:

    def __init__(self, img, target_posn):
        self.image = img
        self.target_posn = target_posn
        (x, y) = target_posn
        self.posn = (x, 0)     # Start ball at top of its column
        self.y_velocity = 0    #    with zero initial velocity

    def update(self):
        self.y_velocity += gravity
        (x, y) = self.posn
        new_y_pos = y + self.y_velocity
        (target_x, target_y) = self.target_posn   # Unpack the position
        dist_to_go = target_y - new_y_pos         # How far to our floor?
        if dist_to_go < 0:                        # Are we under floor?
            self.y_velocity = -0.65 * self.y_velocity     # Bounce
            new_y_pos = target_y + dist_to_go     # Move back above floor
        self.posn = (x, new_y_pos)                # Set our new position.

    def draw(self, target_surface):      # Same as before.
        target_surface.blit(self.image, self.posn)
    def contains_point(self, pt):
      """ Return True if my sprite rectangle contains point pt """
      (my_x, my_y) = self.posn
      my_width = self.image.get_width()
      my_height = self.image.get_height()
      (x, y) = pt
      return ( x >= my_x and x < my_x + my_width and
               y >= my_y and y < my_y + my_height)   
    def handle_click(self):
        self.y_velocity += -2   # Kick it up
        
class DukeSprite:

    def __init__(self, img, target_posn):
        self.image = img
        self.posn = target_posn
        self.anim_frame_count = 0
        self.curr_patch_num = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.anim_frame_count > 0:
           self.anim_frame_count = (self.anim_frame_count + 1 ) % 60
           self.curr_patch_num = self.anim_frame_count // 6

    def draw(self, target_surface):
        patch_rect = (self.curr_patch_num * 50, 0,
                       50, self.image.get_width())
        target_surface.blit(self.image, self.posn, patch_rect)

    def contains_point(self, pt):
         """ Return True if my sprite rectangle contains  pt """
         (my_x, my_y) = self.posn
         my_width = self.image.get_width()
         my_height = self.image.get_height()
         (x, y) = pt
         return ( x >= my_x and x + my_width and y >= my_y and y < my_y + my_height)

    def handle_click(self):
         if self.anim_frame_count == 0:
            self.anim_frame_count = 5

def draw_board(the_board):
    """ Draw a chess board with queens, as determined by the the_board. """

    pygame.init()
    colors = [(255,0,0), (0,0,0)]    # Set up colors [red, black]

    n = len(the_board)         # This is an NxN chess board.
    surface_sz = 480           # Proposed physical surface size.
    sq_sz = surface_sz // n    # sq_sz is length of a square.
    surface_sz = n * sq_sz     # Adjust to exactly fit n squares.

    # Create the surface of (width, height), and its window.
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((surface_sz, surface_sz))

    ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")

    # Use an extra offset to centre the ball in its square.
    # If the square is too small, offset becomes negative,
    #   but it will still be centered :-)
    ball_offset = (sq_sz-ball.get_width()) // 2
    all_sprites = []      # Keep a list of all sprites in the game

    # Create a sprite object for each queen, and populate our list.
    for (col, row) in enumerate(the_board):
        a_queen = QueenSprite(ball,
                   (col*sq_sz+ball_offset, row*sq_sz+ball_offset))
        all_sprites.append(a_queen)
    # Load the sprite sheet
    duke_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load("duke_spritesheet.png")
    
    # Instantiate two duke instances, put them on the chessboard
    duke1 = DukeSprite(duke_sprite_sheet,(sq_sz*2, 0))
    duke2 = DukeSprite(duke_sprite_sheet,(sq_sz*5, sq_sz))
    
    # Add them to the list of sprites which our game loop manages
    all_sprites.append(duke1)
    all_sprites.append(duke2)
    while True:

    # Look for an event from keyboard, mouse, etc.
        ev = pygame.event.poll()
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break;
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key = ev.dict["key"]
            if key == 27:                  # On Escape key ...
                break                      #   leave the game loop.
            if key == ord("r"):
                colors[0] = (255, 0, 0)    # Change to red + black.
            elif key == ord("g"):
                colors[0] = (0, 255, 0)    # Change to green + black.
            elif key == ord("b"):
                colors[0] = (0, 0, 255)    # Change to blue + black.
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # Mouse gone down?
            posn_of_click = ev.dict["pos"]    # Get the coordinates.
            for sprite in all_sprites:
                if sprite.contains_point(posn_of_click):
                    sprite.handle_click()
                    break    
        
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            sprite.update()
          
        # Draw a fresh background (a blank chess board)
        for row in range(n):           # Draw each row of the board.
            c_indx = row % 2           # Alternate starting color
            for col in range(n):       # Run through cols drawing squares
                the_square = (col*sq_sz, row*sq_sz, sq_sz, sq_sz)
                surface.fill(colors[c_indx], the_square)
                # Now flip the color index for the next square
                c_indx = (c_indx + 1) % 2
          
        # Ask every sprite to draw itself.
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            sprite.draw(surface)
        my_clock.tick(60)  # Waste time so that frame rate becomes 60 fps
   
        pygame.display.flip()
    
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    draw_board([0, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2])    # 7 x 7 to test window size
```

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  This is simply too much: dumping your entire program.  You give s description with unresolved references for pronouns and run-on sentences.  Give us minimal code with a clear *demonstration* of a *single* point of error, and we can help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. If I try your code on my computer, what should I do to see the problem? What will happen, and what should happen instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
What happens is that if one executes the code and clicks any box to the right of the Dukesprite, the animation of this will start, what should happen is that this animation should only happen if the Dukesprite is directly clicked

Answer (score 3):

There is `< my_x` missing in the comparisons expression in the method `contains_point` of the class `DukeSprite`:

<s>`return ( x >= my_x and x + my_width and y >= my_y and y < my_y + my_height)`</s>

```py
return ( x >= my_x and x < my_x + my_width and y >= my_y and y < my_y + my_height)
```

Anyway in python you should use [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```py
return my_x <= x < my_x + my_width and my_y <= y < my_y + my_height
```

In pygame you should use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint). The rectangle of the object you can get from the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the method [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) and the position can be set by an keyword argument:

```py
def contains_point(self, pt):
    """ Return True if my sprite rectangle contains  pt """
    my_rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = self.posn)
    return my_rect.collidepoint(pt)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer but I still have the same problem, what happens is that by clicking on any box to the right of the dukesprite this will start the animation what should happen is that the animation should only happen if it occurs click directly on the dukesprite